# How selectively print the content of region.html.twig

Tags: blocks, theming, 9

I'm trying to modify the html of `region.html.twig`
I've used a hook to override the suggestion:

```
function my_theme_theme_suggestions_region_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  if($variables["elements"]["#region"] === 'content' && \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() === 'view.search.page_1') {
    $suggestions[] = "region__content__search";
  }
}
```

The `content` inside the twig is Markup, so I'm trying to use the `elements` array where there are the various blocks to render.

However, if I try something like this

```
{% set classes = [
    'region',
    'region-' ~ region|clean_class,
] %}
{% if content %}
    <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                {{ elements | without('content', 'one_block') }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
                {{ elements.one_block}}
                {{ elements.content }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

In the first col everything is printed. In other words, the filter `without` isn't applied.
The second col is fine - only `one_block` and `content` are printed.

What's more, if I try to

```
{{ dd(elements | without('content', 'one_block')) }}
```

`content` and `one_block` aren't listed, so they seems to be filtered.

Any idea why this happens? How can solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: I was able to replicate the issue in region.html.twig, seems like a Drupal bug.

Comment: Thank you, I've searched in the core's issues and found nothing, so I've [created one](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3199075)